# video capture OK/Retake screen crashes on play

Tags: android, video, video-capture

Whenever I capture a vide and I'm taken to the next screen which is the OK/Retake screen and I try to play the video; it crashes. I think this is because of the parameter `(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)` where I specify my custom path. However; if I don't pass this parameter and allow the video to be stored in the default location; the app does not crash on play button press.

Below is my code:

```
private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 100);

    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    mVideoCaptureUri = mActivity.getExternalCacheDir() +
            "/", ".mp4"
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mVideoCaptureUri);
    takeVideoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(mActivity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        mActivity.startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Crash log:
**android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/cache/1517905670437.mp4 exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how can I resolve this crash

Comment: post the crashlog from logcat please

Comment: added logcat. please check

Comment: this problem happens on API 24 and above only. Did you read about FileProvider?

Comment: Nope. Is there any specific example?

Comment: yes check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed